# script not running through cron. Works fine when executed manually

Tags: unix, cron, aix, hana

I have a shell script where I am calling the hana.scr script from within the main script. The hana.scr contains the below code.

```
chmod 777 /data/auto/SLT.out; rm -rf /data/auto/SLT.out; hdbsql -n plhesappr61 -i 00 -u USR -p $#^F#$GGG -o /data/auto/SLT.out "Select sum("ERPACC_RPPCLNT200"."VABD"."NETWR") FROM "ACC_CLNT"."VFKH" inner join "ACC_CLNT"."VNRO" on ("ACC_CLNT"."VNRO"."VBELN"="ACC_CLNT"."VFKH"."VBELN") where FKART in ('ZFP1','ZFP3') and FKDAT = (select ADD_DAYS (TO_DATE (current_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), -1) "add_days" from dummy) group by FKDAT";
```

When I run the main script manually, it calls this script fine and the SLT.out file is also generated.
But when I schedule it in cron, the main script executes just fine, except for this hana.scr which does not seem to execute because it does not does not even remove the old file as per the second command rm in the hana.scr.

The cron is the same user as the one I run the script manually with. 
I read that if the cron does not get the same environment to run, these issues happen. I tried to import the UNIX profile of the user before executing as the hana.scr as well, but was not successful.

Below is the cron command which runs the main script which calls the hana.scr from within: Used absolute paths..

```
37 0,2,3,4,5,6 * * * /data/esb/auto/./main.sh R > /data/esb/auto/main.log
```

The hana.scr is executed in the below manner:

```
./hana.scr;
check6=$? ;
                                if [ $check6 = "1" ]
                                        then
                                                echo "***********HANA counts were not generated**********"
                                fi
```

Comment: Redirect the cron job's error as well to main.log and see what happens.

Comment: Inside "main.sh" is there some condition based on which "hana.scr" is launched? how exactly the "hana.scr" is launched? Could there be any reason that "hana.scr" is not executed because "main.sh" fails earlier then "hana.scr" would be started ?

Comment: the hana.scr is launched in the below manner: ./hana.scr;
check6=$? ;
                                if [ $check6 = "1" ]
                                        then
                                                echo "***********HANA counts were not generated**********"
                                fi

Comment: Probably it is a PATH issue. Try to call hana.scr using abosolute pathname. Note aside: why chmod 777 a file just before deleting it? To remove a file you need write permission in its directory, not the file itself.

Comment: Changed to absolute path, still nothing. The $? after that also returns 0(complete code is present above). That indicates that this ran fine, but in reality it does not run at all. If it ran, it would have created a new SLT.out file. For chmod, your point noted :)

Answer (score 1):

After `/data/esb/auto/./main.sh` your current directory is not changed to `/data/esb/auto/`. I think you started `main.sh` from the commandline while your `$PWD` was the same as where `hana.scr` was.
Test it from the commandline with

```
cd /
/data/esb/auto/main.sh
```

How to fix?
The worst solution is changing the crontab line into

```
37 0,2,3,4,5,6 * * * cd /data/esb/auto; /data/esb/auto/main.sh R > /data/esb/auto/main.log
```

That is a workaround for the crontab but main.sh still fails when started from a different directory.
Slightly better is using the complete path in main.sh when you call hana.scr

```
myscriptdir=/data/esb/auto
..
${myscriptdir}/hana.scr
```

When you change the folders you need to edit the files and repair the settings.
You can try to use some config file with settings or let main.sh figure out what in which directory it is:
[Getting the source directory of a Bash script from within](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59895/3220113)